# Check if margin-left is a certain percentage

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design, margin, percentage

I ran into a problem when making an easy horizontal slider.
With a right and left arrow (img) the position goes -100% or +100% and this works fine! :)
When the slider is at -400%, the right arrow should disappear, but when i use jquery to check this, nothing happens? Also when the left arrow is at 0% it should disappear.

Here is my code:

```
$('.right img').live('click', function(){
    $('.play').stop(true, true).animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100%"
    }, 1000);
$('.left img').css("visibility", "visible")
if($('.play').css("margin-left")="400%") {
    $('.right img').css("visibility", "hidden")     
    }
});

$('.left img').live('click', function(){
    $('.play').stop(true, true).animate({
        marginLeft: "+=100%"
    }, 1000);

if($('.play').css('margin-left')=='-2520px'){           
    $('.right img').css("visibility", "visible")
}
else if($('.play').css("margin-left")=0) {
    $('.left img').css("visibility", "hidden")
}
});
```

When i use px instead of % it works! But for a responsive code i would like to use %.

Sorry for my bad english :)
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Browsers will normally return a pixel value for `element.style.margin`, so you'll need to check it against a pixel value. Since 100% is equal to the elements width, you can just check if the margin is equal to or greater then the width of the element.

Comment: I only use percentage. The div slider is a certain percentage of the page width and height, so I can't check for pixels because its al in percentage...

Comment: I realize you're only using percentages, but you need to check what the returned value is, so you can compare against that value, and javascript usually returns pixel values, even if you've set it to percentages, but again, you need to check that in the console. Also, you're not comparing anything??? One equal sign sets the value, two equal signs compares the values, three equal signs compares the values with strict type, and you're using one euqal sign, setting the value, not comparing it. Lastly, live() is deprecated, and you should be using on().

Answer (score 1):

**==** is used when comparing numeric values.

**=** is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

and jQuery css property returns pixels instead of percentage, so easiest in this case would be to use JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementsByClass('play').style.marginLeft == "400")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an assignment instead of a comparison:

```
if($('.play').css("margin-left")="400%") {
```

should be:

```
if($('.play').css("margin-left")=="400%") {
```

and

```
else if($('.play').css("margin-left")=0) {
```

should be:

```
else if($('.play').css("margin-left")==0) {
```

Other than that, it's still kind of a spaghetti western way to do what you're trying to do, but that's going to go a long way in understanding why things aren't disappearing when they should, etc...

My suggestion for any overflow hiding, use absolute positioning instead of margins.  But I digress...